# For creating queue and queue not recieving correct variable

Tags: jquery, queue

What's happening is the queue is getting what the value is at the time the queue gets to that function and not the value when the queue was set in the first place. How do I fix this?

```
    ms = false;
    for(var x in Apps['f-game'].m['gD']['game_data']['lr']['sk']) {
        if(Apps['f-game'].m['gD']['game_data']['lr']['sk'][x] == 1) {
            Apps['f-game'].m['aQ'].queue(function () {
                Apps['f-game'].wGBF(x);

                if(!mS) {
                    Apps['f-game'].m['aQ'].delay(200);
                    Apps['f-game'].m['aQ'].queue(function () {
                        Apps['f-game'].wGBP(x, 5);
                    });
                }
                Apps['f-game'].m['aQ'].delay(500);
            });

        }
    }
```

**Examples**
Apps['f-game'].m['gD']['game_data']['lr']['sk'] = {1:1,54:1,115894:1}

The entire file will call Apps['f-game'].wGBP(x, 5); and  x will be 115894 every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'cheating' by using `let varName = data` to force a local scope.